# Solving a Quadratic Equation "Using a Table and a Graph"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I need to find $a\in \Bbb Z, 0\le a\lt10 : f(1 + \frac{a}{10}) = 0$ for a number of different quadratic functions, for example $f(x) = -x^2 + 4x - 3$, by "using a table and a graph". Can someone explain what that actually is, and how one uses the specified methods to solve this sort of problem?

Comment: $$-(x-a)(x-1)=-x^2+4x-3$$

Comment: Could you explain that please

Comment: If $a,1$ be the zeros, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Vieta.27s_formulas

Comment: Here's an idea: why don't you _pay attention in class next time_?

Comment: You don't think I am... I do online @AJMansfield. Its harder to grasp things. Im just trying to get help. You don't need to comment.

Comment: @Desiree At least make an effort to ask in a way that doesn't immediately sound like 'please do my homework for me'. "Here is the first one" indeed!

Comment: I do not what them to do my homework for me im trying to understand. Its my last day of the semester and am just trying to get it all done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help you to factor $$f(x) = -x^2 + 4x - 3 = -(x - 3)(x - 1)$$

Then $$f(x) = 0 \iff x - 3 = 0 \;\text{ or } \; x - 1 = 0$$

As suggested, did you graph the function? You can then visually see where $f(x)$ intersects the $x$-axis: those are the "zeros" of the function.

Comment: Yes, I did graph it using an online calculator, but the parabola does not cross exactly at an x-axis.

Comment: so then I would solve x-a=0 and x-1=0.. a= -1, right?

Comment: Yes, it does: it crosses the x-axis when $f(x) = 0$; and $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = 3$ **or** $x = 1$. Per your question, yes, you solve each of $x - 3 = 0$, $x - 1 = 0$, separately. There are two values of $x$ that are zeros: one is $x = 3$, the other is $x = 1$.

Comment: Why would we use 3.. for the equation x-3=0 if the equation uses a and a would be the first number. I guess I don't understand on that part.

Comment: And my graph shows that the parabola is close to -5 and close to 1 but not exactly on it.

Comment: **Factor.** $f(x): -x^2 + 4x - 3= -(x^2 - 4x + 3) = -(x-1)(x - 3)$. The zeros of a function are when $f(x) = y = 0$, so we solve $f(x) = -(x - 1)(x-3) = 0$. $f(x) = 0$ when either of the factors is zero. Hence when $(x - 1) = 0 $ or when $(x - 3) = 0$. This gives us $x = 1$ or $x = 3$. The parabola intersects the x axis at $x = 1, x = 3$.

Comment: Okay I see now where the 3 comes from.. we we factored -x^2 becomes two x's like you showed −(x−3)(x−1) but what about the 4x in the problem... do we not do anything with that?

Comment: Expand the two factors: $$-(x-3)\cdot (x - 1) = -(x^2 - x - 3x + 3) = -(x^2 - 4x + 3) = -x^2 + 4x - 3$$

Comment: Okay I kind of get it now.. factoring is just confusing to me. Is there other ways to solve these or is factoring really the only way? thanks for your help on that (:

Comment: Not a problem: Glad to help. Do you see that since $f(1) = 0 = f(3)$, then $\;f(1 + \frac a{10})=0 \iff a = 0$ or $a = 20$, but since we need $a \lt 10$, our answer must be $a = 0$?

Comment: I did not see... im not sure what that all means to be honest. Math is my worst subject :/

Comment: The question you posted is essentially asking you to solve for $a$, given $1+\frac 1{10} = 1$ or $1+ \frac a{10} = 3$. ($1$ and $3$ are the two zeros of the function). That's where I got $a = 0$, or $a = 20$, but we throw out $a = 20$ since it's greater than $10$.

Comment: okay I kind of get it a little more now.... so with another problem like that- g(x)= x^2 - 8x, when I graphed it  on -2 and 8 so if it is asking for the smallest zero of the function that would then be -2 right?

Comment: The zeros of $x^2 - 8x = x(x-8)$ are when $x = 0$ or when $x = 8$. So the smallest zero will be $0$. Don't forget to accept the answer if it's been helpful!

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the help! For taking the time to explain it.

Comment: You're welcome, Desiree!  Take time when graphing functions by hand (use graph paper for scale and spacing or you risk being off a tad on intercepts, etc.) and get in the habit of comparing your graph with a calculator or Wolfram Alpha, so you can test how accurate your graphs are. This all will get much easier, over time. Just keep at it! ;-)

Comment: Thanks! :) I do not know how to graph them by hand.. but I do use Wolfram Alpha and I also use meta-calculator. I will keep at it ((:

Comment: @amWhy: Very nice discourse +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you use a table to solve the problem. Make a list of all the allowed values of $a$, the corresponding values of $x$, and the resulting value for $f(x)$

```
 a │  x  │ f(x)
───┼─────┼──────
 0 │ 1.0 │ ?.??
 1 │ 1.1 │ ?.??
 2 │ 1.2 │ ?.??
   ┊     ┊
 9 │ 1.9 │ ?.??
```

Now, looking at your table, for what value of $a$ does $f(x)$ come out as zero?

---

Here is how you use a graph to solve the problem. Plug the equation into a graphing utility, [like this one](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kh42hvnk7t). Now, looking at the graph, for what values of $x$ does $f(x)$ equal zero? For which of the two points can you pick an $a$ such that $1+\frac{a}{10}$ equals $x$?

Comment: Okay so for the first part of the graph 0, 1.0, ?.?? I got 6 but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Desiree nope, try again. You are messing up order of operation.

Comment: @Desiree I just figured out what the error was: you switched the sign of the last term in the equation. You evaluated $−x^2+4x+3$, when the function is actually supposed to be $−x^2+4x-3$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, try the quadratic formula (or factoring, but if you cannot see how to factor it, the quadratic formula will give you what you need anyway). You have that $x= \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ where the quadratic you have is of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$. Therefore, in your case, $a=-1$, $b=4$, and $c=-3$. When you plug these into the formula, you get what you need.

Comment: Thank you! :) it makes more sense now.